# Embed the latest Youtube video to website without a username

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to embed my latest YouTube video to my website and I've tried using this code that was suggested by someone online...

```
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=[USERNAME]" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But I don't have a username for my YouTube channel, I only have a Channel ID. I don't have a unique URL either yet as the one they are offering me isn't what I want.

Does anyone have any other solutions that would working using the channel ID instead of username?

Comment: how can you not have a username for the chanel but still have a chanel? all channels have usernames if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: I don't think usernames work anymore  I tried adding my username but it doesn't pull the video through

Comment: FYI you need at least 100 subs for a username